# trying to pass variables from a powershell function to another

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create 2 variables in a function and then passing them into the second function.
the 2 variables just don't seem to be being passed in.
I Have tried returning the variables but doesn't seem to work either.
what am I missing?

```
enter code here

function get-PSnames 
    {
        $tony = 'tiny'
        $tlony = 'jommy' 
    }

function get-PSadded ([string] $name,[string]$name2)
    {
        $tony + $tlony   
    }

    get-PSnames
    get-PSadded "$tony, $tlony"
```

Comment: Call the function inside your `Get-PSNames` function, unless you want to make your variables global: `Get-PSNames -Name $tony -Name2 $tlony`, functions run in it's own scope and not the global scope not making your variables available to anything else but, that function unless specified using a global variable: `$Global:myvariable`. Also, parameters are passed individually and not as a whole. Currently, you're passing `$tony + $tlony` as a whole instead of individual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in PowerShell are *scoped*, meaning they only exist for the duration of the function that they're created in.

What you'll want to do is create a function that returns the string values:

```
function Get-PSNames
{
  'tiny'
  'jommy'
}
```

You can then assign them to your own variables when you *call* the function:

```
$tony,$tlony = Get-PSNames
```

And pass them as arguments to your other function:

```
function Get-PSAdded([string]$Name, [string]$OtherName)
{
  # Remember to use the same variable names you used when defining the function's parameters
  $Name + $OtherName
}

# call the function 
$tony,$tlony = Get-PSNames

$newName = Get-PSAdded -Name $tony -OtherName $tlony
```

Comment: Thanks for that, would never of got there.

Comment: @TonyMcG You're welcome! If my answer solves you problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark outline on the left :-)